# Trigonometry word problem involving a window?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A walls is 10 feet tall and is 15 feet from a house. A window in the house is 30.5 feet above the ground.A fire escape slide attaches to the bottom of the window and to the top of the tall of the opposite window.How long a slide must be purchased?

I drew a picture but I am having trouble finding the exact length of the fire slide from the given info.

Comment: "and to the top of the tall of the opposite window" What does this mean?

Comment: You posted your first question less than 1 hour ago; and you are already unhappy that you did not get answers as complete or as quickly as you wanted? We are not at your beck and call; try exercising some patience.

Comment: How is this not either homework, or an exam that you've managed to smuggle a smartphone into?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  the horizontal distance is 15 feet.  The vertical distance is 30.5-10 feet.  Time for Mr. Pythagoras.

Comment: many thanks for your help.